# React native mapping through array with object childs - working different as in react web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this array which contains objects:

```
var tmp_array = [
 { headline: "Test", text: "Test text", send_at: "test date" }
];
```

Now in the web react environment I was able to map through this array and return its values to a variable which can then be rendered.

So I used the same approach:

```
    var i = -1;
    var WholeNews = tmp_array.map(function(news){
      i++;
      return(
        <View key={i}>
          <Text>{news.headline}</Text>
          <View>
            <Text>{news.text}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>);
    });
```

After the mapping has finished it should be rendered as following:

```
return(
  <View>
     {WholeNews}
  </View>
);
```

Unfortunately I receive a warning in my iOS Simulator which says:

> Objects are not valid as a React child(found: object with keys {WholeNews}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFrament(object) from the React-addons.

I am not sure whether I am missing out something completely or react native simply doesn't support a mapping through an array as in my example.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should work:

```
WholeNews() {
  return tmp_array.map(function(news, i){
    return(
      <View key={i}>
        <Text>{news.headline}</Text>
        <View>
          <Text>{news.text}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  });
}

render() {
  return(
    <View>
      {this.WholeNews()}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: How would I access state within the 2nd `return` function in `WholeNews()`?

Comment: @kojow7 what is the part you need to be explained?

Comment: Explaining what was wrong with the OP and what was changed in yours would be a great help in understanding what the error message means. Simply saying "This should work" does not offer any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method instead of `map`:

```
   var WholeNews =[];
   tmp_array.forEach(function(news, i){
      WholeNews.push(
        <View key={i}>
          <Text>{news.headline}</Text>
          <View>
            <Text>{news.text}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>);
    });
```

And note from where you can get the `i` index..

Comment: If you do things like this, you have to return WholeNews as the render method