# Do a loop in a Render in react native

Tags: react-native, loops, view, return, push

i'm trying to do a loop in my render.
I put in a variable a lot of 'uri' with push (in a loop)

```
test.push(data.link)
```

And now, with pop, i want to draw all the pictures.
Right now i'm doing that manually like that

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={ { width: 400, height: 400 } } source={ { uri: test.pop() } } />
        <Image style={ { width: 400, height: 400 } } source={ { uri: test.pop() } } />
        <Image style={ { width: 400, height: 400 } } source={ { uri: test.pop() } } />
        <Image style={ { width: 400, height: 400 } } source={ { uri: test.pop() } } />
        <Image style={ { width: 400, height: 400 } } source={ { uri: test.pop() } } />
        <Image style={ { width: 400, height: 400 } } source={ { uri: test.pop() } } />
      </View>
      )
```

But i can't draw all the pictures because i need to do that for each pictures. Someone has an idea of how I could do to display all the photos or a specific amount without having to do them one per pone like above

Comment: Why not use something like map ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286175/react-native-mapping-through-array-with-object-childs-working-different-as-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't `pop()` your array.
Instead, you can use `map`, wich will increment every entry of your array and do something with it.
For example:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {test.map(link => (
      <Image style={ { width: 400, height: 400 } } source={ { uri: link } } />
    ))}
  </View>
)
```